# What is the 2-Lebesgue measure of a set with Hausdorff dimension $<2$?

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, fractals, geometric-measure-theory

Define $\mu_n$ as the Lebesgue measure on  $\mathbb{R^n}$,  $H^d$ as the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, and $d_H(S)$ as the Hausdorff dimension of set $S$.

I suspect that if a set $S$ has a non-integer Hausdorff dimension $d$ then all Lebesgue measures of $S$ at or below $\lfloor d \rfloor$ will be infinite and all those at or above $\lceil d \rceil$ will be zero.

In other words, I conjecture that:

$$d_H(S)=:d \notin \mathbb{N} \implies \mu_k(S)=\infty \;\forall k<d \\ \text{ and } \mu_k(S)=0 \;\forall k>d$$

My reasoning is as follows:

When $k$ is an integer $H^k(S) = C_k\mu_k(S)$ for some positive constant $C_k<\infty$.

Also, $H^c(S)=\infty$ if $c<d$ and $H^c(S) = 0$ if $c>d$.

Therefore, $\mu_c(S)=\infty$ for all integers $c<d$ and is $0$ for all integers $c>d$.

Is this correct? If not, then what failed in my reasoning.

Comment: Rather than try to parse all your symbolic stuff, I'll simply state some things that will probably handle your questions. For integer dimension values, Hausdorff and Lebesgue (outer) measure are proportional. If a set has a pos. Hausdorff dimension, then its measure in any lower dimension is infinite (indeed, not even $\sigma$-finite) and its measure in any higher dimension is zero. The set's measure AT the dimension of the set can be zero or infinite (indeed, it can fail to be $\sigma$-finite), and all three possibilities exist for subsets of ${\mathbb R}^n$ for any dimension LESS than $n.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thanks for the comment .. I was using the symbols to make my question precise as it’s hard to get right with words. I understand the behavior of the hausdorff measure on subsets. What I want to know is if the 2-Lebesgue measure of a set with Hausdorff dimension, say, 1.3, is 0

Comment: Yes, as this is essentially (up to a multiplicative constant) asking if the 2-Hausdorff measure of a set with Hausdorff dimension 1.3 is zero.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Ah, great! That was exactly my conjecture. My reasoning was that since n-Lebesgue and n-Hausdorff are w/in a mulitplicative constant for integer n, then we can use exactly what you said above to justify this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Hausdorff dimension is less than 2 then by definition the set has zero H^2 measure. Since Lebesgue measure on R^2 equals the Hausdorff measure H^2, up to a constant if your definition of Hausdorff measure does not use the correcting constant, it follows that the Lebesgue measure of the set is zero as well.

See my playlist on Hausdorff measures for proofs of such facts about them:
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_c66HM3gCsjf5HVsRRFmDh3mInujZXHp